# Dictionary data structure returns nil in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am trying to implement a dictionary data structure in swift that stores an Array of Strings. I have declared it like:

```
var journeyDetails = [Int: [String]]()
```

When I want to append an actual string to it, I do

```
if let journeys = fetchedData["journeys"] as? [[String: Any]]{
                        var nr_of_journey : Int = 0
                        for journey in journeys{
                            self.journeyDetails[nr_of_journey]?.append("The starting date and time of the journey are: "+String(describing: journey["startDateTime"]))
                        }
}
nr_of_journey = nr_of_journey + 1
```

etc etc. However, `journeyDetails` keeps returning `nil`. Should I do any other type of initialization?  Why is the data not appended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially there are no keys or values in `journeyDetails` so every use of `self.journeyDetails[nr_of_journey]` returns `nil`.

If you are using Swift 4, you can specify a default value to be used if there currently isn't a value for the given key.

Update the line:

```
self.journeyDetails[nr_of_journey]?.append("The starting date and time of the journey are: "+String(describing: journey["startDateTime"]))
```

to:

```
self.journeyDetails[nr_of_journey, default: []].append("The starting date and time of the journey are: "+String(describing: journey["startDateTime"]))
```

This provides a default empty array if there currently isn't a value for the given `nr_of_journey` key.